# I am struggling to get a 200 success request for my Heroku-hosted API on Rapid API for GET requests. I only receive a '404 page not found' error

Tags: go, heroku, postman, rapidapi

I am consistently receiving a `404 page not found` error for my API calls when using the Rapid API URL for the request. My Go API server is currently running in Heroku, and POST requests are successful when I run them using the built in API platform on Rapid APIs website. I do not understand why I am not getting a successful response for GET requests. I have the correct `X-RapidAPI-Host` and `X-RapidAPI-Key` for the GET request, these are the same ones I use for the POST requests that work. Bare in mind I have a MongoDB Atlas database that I store my data in. I don't know if this has any impact on these unexpected results.

I checked my heroku logs and I can see that the request fails instantly.

I have replicated this request using Postman and I have been able to successfully send new data and store them in my MongoDB Atlas DB via the Rapid API POST request; but even on Postman I still cannot get the GET requests to work. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: While your question contains some details, it does not contain sufficient detail for others to fully understand your issue and provide a solution. It is recommend that you post a minimal repro of your issue as a question so that we may try out your code and identify issues. It would also help if you included details of the `POST` (headers, data etc.), the attempted `GET` and the errors that you receive. That you're unable to use an alternative client to access the API suggests that the API is at fault (and possibly doesn't support the method via `GET`).